# Setinterval running in nodejs auto stops when hosting in Cpanel, It works perfect in localhost

Tags: node.js, timer, cpanel, setinterval

I was running a setInterval in Nodejs at every 1 second interval. But when I hosted it on Cpanel after 30 minutes website inactivity It stops running. But in locahost it works without any issue. I am passing a socket in every second with this setinterval. Why the issue happen?

```
  let intervalId = setInterval(() => {
                var io = req.app.get('socketio');
                let time = req.body.time++;
                console.log(time)
                let timerId = intervalId[Symbol.toPrimitive]();
                io.to(req.user.email).emit("socketTimer", { intervalId: timerId, time});
            }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your NodeJS app through the CloudLinux NodeJS Selector, it might be an issue with the Apache Passenger, which is handling this. You might want to try running your app through SSH as you do on localhost and see if it happens again. If you can't seem to find a solution for that, then I would suggest switching to a NodeJS specific web hosting provider.

Comment: Now I changed my method by comparing timestamps in the database. It feels good and then we don't lose our data if the server crashes.